# Swipeable area in react-native-swiper

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

Is there any way we can set the swipe able area in react-native-swiper? For example, from the mock screen, I would like the screen to be swiped only when the user swipe on the area marked by black border.

PS: The default behaviour is to let the screen swipe from any where in the swiper component.

[Mock Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCGD5.png)